# Automatically capitalize first letter in TextBoxes

Tags: wpf, textbox

I am creating a wpf application. I have to make all textbox first letter to capital, if a user entered in small then it should be formatted in capital on mouse out.I need the best way to do it, please someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way of doing it greatly depends on how you are doing your app, but @H.B.'s answer is probably the way to go. 
For the sake of completeness, another way if doing it would be to use a converter like so:

```
<!-- Your_Window.xaml -->
<Window x:Class="..."
        ...
        xmlns:cnv="clr-namespace:YourApp.Converters">
  <Window.Resources>
    <cnv.CapitalizeFirstLetterConverter x:Key="capFirst" />
  </Window.Resources>
  ...
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource capFirst}}" />
```

This assumes that your window's data context is set to an instance of a class that has a read/write property named SomeProperty of type string.
The converter itself would be something like this:

```
// CapitalizeFirstLetterConverter.cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
namespace YourApp.Converters {
  [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
  public class CapitalizeFirstLetterConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      // this will be called after getting the value from your backing property
      // and before displaying it in the textbox, so we just pass it as-is
      return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      // this will be called after the textbox loses focus (in this case) and
      // before its value is passed to the property setter, so we make our
      // change here
      if (value is string) {
        var castValue = (string)value;
        return char.ToUpper(castValue[0]) + castValue.Substring(1);
      }
      else {
        return value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can learn more about converters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion).

Comment: Also, in the Text Binding, if you make `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, this converter will run real-time instead of when the TextBox loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

You could put a style into the `Application.Resources` to handle `LostFocus` on all `TextBoxes`, then you just need to change the Text property accordingly.

```
<!-- App.xaml - Application.Resources -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="TextBox_LostFocus" />
</Style>
```

```
// App.xaml.cs - App
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        tb.Text = Char.ToUpper(tb.Text[0]) + tb.Text.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the game, but if anybody else needs it this dll capitalizes the first letter in realtime.  For example, you don't need to mouse out.

http://www.mardymonkey.co.uk/blog/auto-capitalise-a-text-control-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a converter but not a converter like @ssarabando, because it is bugged.
Here's the code of the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
namespace SistemaContable.GUI.WPF.Converters
{
    public class CapitalizeFirstLetter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string stringToTitleCase = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value.ToString());
                return stringToTitleCase;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to reference it in a "ResourceDictionary" or in your "App.xaml":

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:SistemaContable.GUI.WPF.Converters">
    <converters:CapitalizeFirstLetter x:Key="CapitalizeFirstLetter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtNombre" Text="{Binding Usuario.Nombre, Converter={StaticResource CapitalizeFirstLetter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```